# How can I work this out?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I am making a game where insects from above the screen move downwards to the bottom. The object is for the player to kill these insects with his/her mouse. When killed the insect should show a kill frame, where I have put in. The kill frame will stay there for 3 seconds and the object will be removed. This will also increase the player's score.

This code is written inside the insect:

```
function kill(event:MouseEvent):void
{
this.dead = true;

}
```

This code is written inside the background movieclip frame.

```
function moveEnemies():void
{
var tempEnemy:MovieClip;

for (var i:int =enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    tempEnemy = enemies[i];
    if (tempEnemy.dead)
    {

        tempEnemy.gotoAndStop(21);
        var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(3000);
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
        myTimer.start();
}
}
}
function timerListener (e:TimerEvent):void
{

for (var i:int =enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
{
if (tempEnemy.dead)
{
    score++;
    roachLevel.score_txt.text = String(score);
removeEnemy(i);

}


}
}
function removeEnemy(id:int)
{

removeChild(enemies[id]);
enemies.splice(id,1);
}
```

The problem that I am experiencing with this, is that whenever I click on the insects they stay there. I click on another one it stays there. Then another, then after a while they disappear and the score increases. Sometimes the death frame doesn't appear and they die as soon as I touch them. Could you please tell me how I can solve this?

Comment: The problem is that you are removing enemies once every 3 seconds. You should do that when you click on the enemy instead.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to relocate score adding to enemy class, and assign a timeout to the particular squished enemy instead of the base class. The best place to do it is in `kill()` function.

```
function kill(e:MouseEvent):void {
    this.dead=true;
    gotoAndStop(21);
    flash.utils.setTimeout(removeSelf,3000);
}
function removeSelf():void {
    this.parent.removeChild(this);
}
```

Now, adjust the mechanics for scoring and tracking objects. First, if an object becomes `dead`, you immediately remove it from the array of enemies (it will handle its removal on its own) and give score for it. And second, all the other functional should be preserved.

```
for (var i:int=enemies.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    var tempEnemy=enemies[i];
    if (tempEnemy.dead) {
        score++;
        enemies.splice(i,1);
    } else {
        tempEnemy.y++; // or other move function
    }
}
```

This loop should be in an enterframe listener, so it'll be called once per frame. Also combining splicing and moving like here eliminates the need of placing movement code elsewhere, as you iterate through the array anyway.